# Realize a custom table view cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I would like to implement into my application a selection style to the Tableview's Cell as the figure. Could you tell me how i can do to ? i can't find a tutorial to do it in swift 3.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Ppbk.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the red bar on the left? I would create the red UIView and just set `hidden` to `true` in `prepareForReuse` and on creation. Then in your `UITableViewDelegate` `didSelectRowAt:`, you can set hidden to `false`.

Comment: yes i mean the red bar , but from your answer i can't understand how realize it

Comment: So when you create the layout for that cell, you just need to have a UIView whose background color is red. Create the autolayout constraints to make it the width you want and positioned where you want. Then it's as simple as hiding it (setting `redView.hidden = true`) and unhiding it when the user has selected the row. You know when the user selects the row through that delegate call.